# Probability distribution for number of heads obtained in a biased coin

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm a home-schooled high school student struggling with the following question. Any insights/tips on how to solve this would be highly appreciated.

A biased coin is tossed three times. The probability distribution for H, the number of heads obtained, is shown in the following table.

```
h          0       1       2       3
P(H = h)   0.512   0.384   0.096   a
```

1) Find the probability of obtaining a head each time the coin is tossed.

2) Give another discrete random variable that is related to these trials, and calculate the probability that its value is greater than the value of H.

Comment: Can you calculate $a$?  Can you work out what binomial distribution this is?

Comment: Hint:  If $p$ is the probability of getting $H$ on a single toss, then express the probability of getting no Heads in three tosses as a function of $p$.

Comment: You could have just edited your [last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3712131/321264) instead of reposting.

Answer (score 0):

If we say that the probability of getting heads is $p$, then the probability of getting $3$ heads in $3$ tosses is $p^3$.  You aren't told what the probability of getting $3$ heads is, but since all the probabilities must add up to 1 you can get it by $a = 1-(.512+.384+.096) = .008$.  Setting $p^3 = .008$, solving for $p$ gives $p=.2$.

I'm not exactly sure what they're going for in part 2), but one thing you could look at would be the number of tails.  There are more tails than heads if there are $0$ or $1$ heads, so the probability is $.512+.384=.896$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us restate what we know.

We toss the coin three times.

In each toss the outcome may either be heads or tails. As there are only two outcomes, we have a Bernoulli trial.

We are using the same coin. This means that even if the coin is biased, the bias remains the same throughout all the tosses. Thus the probability of getting heads remains constant throughout.

From these facts we can recognize that the number of heads will follow a binomial distribution
$$
b(k; n, p) = {n \choose k} p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
Now we know that if this equation should coincide the the table given, we require that
$$
b(0; 3, p) = {3 \choose 0} p^{0}(1-p)^{3} = (1-p)^3 = 1 -3p + 3p^2 -p^3 = 0.512
$$
Now this cubic equation is not that easy to solve, so we can instead see if we can leverage some extra info from our table. We also require that 
$$
b(1; 3, p) = {3 \choose 1} p^{1}(1-p)^{2} = 3p(1-p)^2 = 3p -6p^2 + 3p^3 = 0.384
$$
Now we are getting somewhere! Using the two equations we can eliminate the 3rd order term in the equation
$$
3\cdot b(0; 3, p) + b(1; 3, p) = 3 -9p + 9p^2 -3p^3 + 3p -6p^2 + 3p^3 = 3\cdot 0.512 + 0.384 \\
b(0; 3, p) + b(1; 3, p) = 3 -6p + 3p^2 = 1.92
$$
This quadratic equation we can solve! The possible solutions are
$$
p = 0.2 \quad \text{or} \quad p = 1.8
$$
Now $p$ is supposed to be a probability so the latter doesn't really make sense. We discard this solution and assume that $p=0.2$. Let use the final entry of the table to confirm that we are right
$$
{3 \choose 2} (0.2)^{2}(0.8)^{1} = 0.096
$$
TADA! As our calculation corresponds with the table, this must be the correct value of $p$. We are finally ready to compute $a$ as 
$$
a = b(3, 3, 0.2) = {3 \choose 3} (0.2)^{3}(0.8)^{0} = 0.2^3 = 0.008
$$